# How to improve network performance between two Win 2008 KMV guest having virtio driver already?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have two physical servers with Ubuntu 10.04 server on them. They are connected with a 1Gbps card over a gigabit switch. Each of these host servers has one Win 2008 guest VM. Both VMs are well provisioned (4 cores, 12GB RAM), RAW disks.

My asp.net/sql server applications are running much slower compared to very similar physical setups.

Both machines are setup to use virtio for disk and network. I used iperf to check network performance and I get:
Physical host 1 -----> Physical Host 2: 957 Mbits/sec
Physical host 1 -----> Win 08 Guest 1: 557 Mbits/sec
Win 08 Guest 1  -----> Phy host 1: 182 Mbits/sec
Win 08 Guest 1  -----> Win 08 Guest 2: 111 Mbits /sec

My app is running on Win08 Guest 1 and Guest 2 (web and db). There is a huge drop in network throughput (almost 90%) between the two guest. Further the throughput does not seem to be symmetric between host and guest as well.

The CPU utilization on the guests and hosts is less than 2% right now (we are just testing right now).

Apart from this, there have been random slow downs in the network to as low as 1 Mbits/sec making the whole application unusable.

Any help to trouble shoot this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. What host OS is used?
2. for every one of the NICs `ethtool -k $NIC` and it's probably a good idea to disable offloads with
   'ethtool -K $NIC tso off ; ethtool -K $NIC gso off'
3. bridged or NAT networking?
4. Where are the virtio drivers from? Are they signed?
5. IPv4 or 6?
6. is ToE enabled in the guests?

Comment: 1. Host OS: Ubuntu 10.04
2. This is on the host? I did this and got "no offload settings changed". Assuming it is disabled.
3. Bridged. Do you want the config output?
4. From RedHat and they are signed from what I can tell. http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/images/

5. IPV4. But I have not disable IPV6 on the host or guest. IPV6 has some random address. Never have paid attention to it till now.

6. I have not done TOE explicitly, so not sure. I check the RedHad VirtIO Ethernet Adapter Propertes, the only thing that could be relates Offloast Tx LSO?

Comment: 1. Can you try on a fedora host? seen ubuntu kvm builds acting up a lot. 2. `ethtool -k eth0` - post the output 3. no, bridges is usually good enough. 4. ok 5. ok 6. `netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled` check settings afterwards, disable LSO if you see it still on

Comment: 1. I can switch, but it will be some work. Can plan for this.
2. ethtool -k eth0:
Offload parameters for eth0:
Cannot get device GRO settings: Operation not permitted
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
scatter-gather: on
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: off
large-receive-offload: off

Comment: Running the netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled command on windows - should improve performance? I will try it shortly.

Comment: the netsh command will improve IIS -> network performace. On the host, you have TSO and GSO on, you need to turn them off `ethtook -K eth0 TSO off` and the same for GSO

Comment: I did this but the performance remains unchanged. In general the application performance is slow (page load times, etc).  I am not sure what else to do, contemplating going back  to physical hardware based machines for now.

Comment: try it on fedora or RHEL first.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. It will take a little time as the server are remote. Would recommend using xen or something else? Just based on experience.

Comment: no, I'm a KVM guy all the way :)

Comment: Ok!I love how easy KVM is. I have to believe that the issues are to do with something in my current setup. I really want to take, this approach move to using these with OpenNebula.... someday soon. Can you kindly point me to the best RHEL/Fedora starting points for moving towards Fedora? CentOS will work too?

Comment: the latest centos is 5.6, while it's OK for KVM, Fedora or RHEL6 is definitely more efficient and feature-rich. Fedora is a bit too cutting-edge of course, but I know of people who use it in pretty large clusters and are happy